# C# WPF - Input Validation - Can't use decimal points (periods) in TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, input, data-binding

I have input validation using IDataErrorInfo but it's preventing me from using decimal points (periods) in my TextBox. Trying to input `1.222` for example doesn't work. It just stops at the 1 and doesn't register the `.` key press--no debug output either. It's also still trying to accept my input (which throws an exception) even though the validation shows that it's the wrong format. How can I fix this?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Density, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Name="tb_density" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="8" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private MyViewModel m_ViewModel;
m_ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
DataContext = m_ViewModel;

private void Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    Console.WriteLine("Density: " + (1 * Convert.ToDouble(tb_density.Text))).ToString();
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace foobar{

    class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo {

        private double m_density;

        public MyViewModel () {

        }

        public double Density {

            get {

                return m_density;
            }
            set {

                if (m_density!= value) {

                    m_density= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Density");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {

            if (PropertyChanged != null) {

                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public string Error {

            get { return "...."; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Will be called for each and every property when ever its value is changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Name of the property whose value is changed</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string this[string columnName] {

            get {

                return Validate(columnName);
            }
        }

        private string Validate(string propertyName) {

            // Return error message if there is error on else return empty or null string
            string validationMessage = string.Empty;

            switch (propertyName) {

                case "Density":
                    if(!double.TryParse(Density.ToString(), out _)) {

                        validationMessage = "Error";
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return validationMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is rising to the surface because you have UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged.  This implies that every time you type something on the keyboard, the error validation gets triggered.  So if you type "1", you currently have no errors.  But if you next type ".", you now have a textbox that contains "1." which is going to fail validation because it is not a real number.  If you change UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, then it will only evaluate the error validation after you leave the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something that looks as follows:

```
private double _density;
public string Density{
 get => _density.ToString();
 set 
 {
   if(double.TryParse(value, out var density){
     _density = density;
   }
 }
```

Btw. your code probably don't work because of `if (m_density!= value)`
when you add dot to one, '1.' still equals '1' so the value is not updated.